# How to do color coding source

Tags: language-agnostic, coding-style, code-formatting

How do they color code source code in an IDE. What is the basic indea behind it? What are they tokens they look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common approach that I know of is the use of single- or multi-line regexes, depending on language syntax.

For IDEs with syntax files, the IDE compiles the file into a regex on first load of relevant file.

Answer (score 0):

Usually doing simple lexing on the source code, e.h. with regexp-s.

Sometimes interacting with the compiler, or some other syntactic parser, to provide more useful (semantic) information.

The syntactic colorization is always dependent upon the language (i.e. the file extension).

Answer (score 0):

You either parse the language completely, or just look for known patterns with e.g. regexes. There is no single method for all languages, each requires its own set of rules.

Parsing usually produces better quality, but regex rules are easier to produce.